# Can not generate configuration file for Google Analytics integration in Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to integrate Google Analytics with my app so I need the configuration file for that as per document suggest in this link 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

When I try to create it I receive the following error message **"Your operation was forbidden."**, see the image bellow:

[image]

Any idea how can I solve this issue? Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?